# Kernel Error while using memcpy in the kernel module to change the content of the buffer passed as argument to the exported function

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have two kernel modules where first module had one function exported and second module uses this function to read spi data. sample program is given below
Module-1:

```
int spi_fun(uint8_t *tx_buf, uint8_t *rx_buf,int len)
{
    spi_sync_txrx(tx_buf,rx_buf,len);
}
```

Module-2:

```
void dummy_fun()
{
    uint8_t tx[4]={0};
    uint8_t rx[4]={0};
    spi_fun(tx,rx,4);
}
```

the above mentioned scenario is working fine. If I declare a local rx buffer(spi_data[4]) inside spi_fun(), and use memcpy to copy spi_data contents to the rx_buf, kernel is crashing with error as given below
New Module-2 fun:
Module-1:

```
int spi_fun(uint8_t *tx_buf, uint8_t *rx_buf,int len)
{
    uint8_t spi_data[4];
    spi_sync_txrx(tx_buf,spi_data,len);
    memcpy(rx_buf, spi_data, len); //here error
}
```

Kernel Error:

> Internal error: Accessing user space memory outside uaccess.h
> routines: 96000045 [#1] PREEMPT SMP

I have used copy_from_user/copy_to_user functions, but i was getting target buffer as zeroes.

Does anyone experienced this issue???

Comment: What is done in the body of `spi_sync_txrx()`?  Original info suggests `rx_buf` references a user address, is that true?   Also what is your kernel version?

Comment: It would help to get more context about your buffers, esepcially in this case rx_buf. Your mention copy_to/from_user(), but we would need to see how you have used them, as this may be the problem and not the code you have exposed here.

Comment: @Milag `spi_sync_txrx()` is a prebuilt function for SPI transfer. `rx_buf` is not a user address, It is a local buffer in another kernel module. am using Kernel version 4.14

Comment: @Longfield  `int spi_fun(uint8_t *tx_buf, uint8_t *rx_buf,int len)  
{  
    uint8_t spi_data[4];   
    spi_sync_txrx(tx_buf,spi_data,len);   
    copy_from_user(rx_buf, spi_data, len); //copy_to_user(rx_buf, spi_data, len);  
}`     this is my code for copy to/from user. this case if i print rx_buf contents, it is always showing zeror but spi_data has proper data.

Comment: Actually copy_to/from_user is failing. Thats why it was read as zeros

Comment: Even if I change the content of the rx_buff from the module2, am getting the same error.  <Internal error: Accessing user space memory outside uaccess.h routines: 96000045 [#1] PREEMPT SMP>

Comment: The error is not in spi_fun.  You are passing incorrect arguments. What is the value of len?

Comment: Where is `spi_sync_txrx()` defined? I have grepped the entire source of kernel version 4.14 and could not find it.

Comment: @stark len is 5 bytes. If I use 'memcpy(rx_buf, spi_data, len-1)', am not seeing error. Even i tried to change the buffer size to 6 and copied 5 bytes using memcpy, still observing error. Am able to copy only 4bytes max using memcpy.

Comment: @IanAbbott sorry for the typo, it is `spi_sync_transfer`. I think here `spi_sync_transfer()` doesn't matter. If I simply use `memcpy(rx_buf, spi_data, len)` where len is more than 4, am getting same error.

Comment: Since `spi_data` is only 4 bytes long, you cannot copy more than 4 bytes to or from that buffer.

Comment: @IanAbbott If I change it to 5 also, same observation.